# Click radio button the fill two input text in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button

[image]

I am trying to associate a radio button with a specified two(2) text input. As you can see in
the picture, there are two options "weekly & monthly". If I choose weekly or monthly there will be default a date in (input type="text" id="from") & (input type="text" id="to") it will fill at the same event.


So far I can display one date value in a input text.

PHP script below, I'm using to get monthly cut-off

```
$currentday = date('d');

if ($currentday >= 21){
    $to = date('m/').'20'.date('/Y');
    $from = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($to. ' - 14 days'));
    echo $from;
}elseif ($currentday >= 5){
    $to = date('m/').'05'.date('/Y');
    $from = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($to. ' - 14 days'));
    echo $from;      
}
```

Hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a bit unclear which event u r referring to for changing inputs in text box  ?

Comment: I'm trying to say that if I click the one radio button, it will display a date in id:from & id:to.

Comment: So you do you call your PHP script with an ajax request after you clicked one of the radio buttons? And then u try to fill in the response from ajax request into your text fields?

Comment: yes i did.     function to(val) { 
        var txt=document.getElementById("to").value; 
        txt = val
        document.getElementById("to").value=txt; 
    }

Comment: Can you show us also your javascript and html?

Comment: how can i paste it here in a good format?

Comment: Paste the content into the answer textarea and use the {} button to mark it as code.